¿expresión regular para limitar número de caracteres en email?
tengo la siguiente linea de codigo para la validacion de un mail:


let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

console.log(pattern.test("email@email.com"))



me gustaría saber como limitar el número de caracteres tanto para el nombre de usuario como al dominio, por ejemplo:

el nombre un minimo de 3 caracteres
el dominio un minimo de 3
después del punto un minimo de 2


Al finalizar cada uno pones algo como esto: {3,} y en el caso de los dos caracteres después del punto, en vez de un tres va un dos

Asi:
let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]{3,}@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

function validarEmail(email) {
    return pattern.test(email);
}

Lógicamente se puede interpretar:
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-]{3,}` : Coincide con la parte del nombre de usuario con un mínimo de 3 caracteres.
[a-zA-Z0-9-]{3,} : Coincide con la parte del dominio con un mínimo de 3 caracteres.
.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ : Coincide con la parte del dominio de nivel superior con un mínimo de 2 caracteres.
Existen herramientas en línea que ayudan a crear y verificar expresiones regulares, allí se pueden probar hasta que cumpla exactamente con el requisito.

que cambios hiciste y por que resuelven, lo que esta en tu comentario arriba deberia ser parte de tu respuesta, saludos.

Funciono a la perfeccion! gracias! habia intentado pero no me salia pero ahora si.

Si, Francisco IA Lover
tiene razon. He complementado mi respuesta adecuadamente.
